# raspberry connection to router prevents script from running

Tags: raspberry-pi, router

I have a script on my raspberry that should get data from a site in the internet.
I want it to get this data as soon the raspberry boots up, so I added a line to the rc.local script to start my script, because according to the information I have this is the last init script to run. The my script runs in an infinite loop, so when I login it is supposed to be running but it is not. I made another script and added another line in the rc.local script start it too. My second script also runs in an infinite loop but it does not "talks" to the internet. After rebooting and logging in I found the my second script running but not my first.

The way I was connecting to my raspberry (in my working place):

- the raspberry is connected to my router;
- my local computer is also connected to the router;
- the router is connecting to the internet;

Trying to find out what the problem is I brougth the raspberry to my house, but because I don't have a router there I connected the raspberry directly to my laptop. To my surprise when I logged in to the raspberry my to scripts were running.

So now I suppose that somehow the router connection (that is working very well with everything else) is stoping or preventing my first script from start.

Could anyone give me a hint to how I can prevent this problem or solve it?

Comment: The first step is probably capturing any error output from your script to see why it is not running.

Comment: I'm new to linux. Can you tell me how can I capture the error output by my script?

Comment: Take a look at the `REDIRECTION` section of the `bash` man page for details.  The short answer is to append `> /tmp/myscript.log 2>&1` to the line that invokes your script; this will redirect *stdout* (`>`) and *stderr* (`2>`) to the specified file.  If you discover any errors, you should *update your question* rather than posting them as comments.  You may also want to show in your question (a) how you are calling your script from `rc.local` and (b) what your script looks like.

Comment: To call the script from rc.local I added "/path/to/the/script/script_one.py &" to the line before "exit 0" of rc.local.